# check certain index positions for a char

Tags: java, if-statement

```
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
   String str = keyboard.next();

   int strlen = str.length();
   //char lastchar = str.charAt(strlen - 1);
   char lastchar2 = str.charAt(strlen - 2);
   if (lastchar2 = 'l'){
   System.out.print("L is in that position");}
```

I was wondering how i can check if a certain index is a certain letter within the if statement, Thanks

Comment: I can not get you. Can you try to explain it in more details?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
if (lastchar2 = "l"){
```

Use

```
if (lastchar2 == 'l'){ //single quotes as we represent String literals with double quotes and "==" since we use "=" as an assignment operator and not for comparison.
```

Note aside: You may need to validate that your input string (str) has atleast two characters in it.

Comment: ok thanks ill try that, what is the logical difference @almas shaikh

Comment: can you paste your modified code in your question please? didnt work doesnt explain anything. Please be specific what you entered and what was that you expected i.e. why didnt worked.

Comment: you still have "=" can you change it to "==" as per answer?

Answer (score 0):

To test a char at a given index:

```
if (str.charAt(i) == 'x')
```

You may also consider:

```
if (str.endsWith("l"))
```